# Выбор уникальных из массива по ключу (наверное так назову)

Tags: php

У меня есть список. Должны выводится все, НО до тех пор, пока не найдутся с одинаковым именем, как например Anna. И вот тогда должна остаться та Anna, у которой в адресе *mail.ru. Но это только в том, случае если с одинаковым именем больше одного. Например Ivan должен остаться так как он один. Как более лаконично реализовать? Список большой на самом деле более 500 чел.

```
$entries[0]["displayname"]="Ivan"
$entries[0]["mail"]="123@mail"
$entries[1]["displayname"]="Anna"
$entries[1]["mail"]="aaa@yandex.ru"
$entries[2]["displayname"]="Bob"
$entries[2]["mail"]="bbb@yandex.ru"
$entries[3]["displayname"]="Anna"
$entries[3]["mail"]="123@mail.ru"
```

Comment: в powershell я применял группировку, сперва всех с один именем, а из групп убираем уже таких то таких то... при условии что count >1. А тут запутался..

Comment: оставаться должен последний email или mail.ru ?

Comment: -весь email как есть, должен оставаться и displayname должен остаться (весь массив). В противном случае должен весь массив второй Анны (с почтой на конце mail.ru) удален через unset то есть весь entries[3] не нужен вместе именем и почтой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$entries[0]["displayname"]="Ivan";
$entries[0]["mail"]="123@mail";
$entries[1]["displayname"]="Anna";
$entries[1]["mail"]="aaa@yandex.ru";
$entries[2]["displayname"]="Bob";
$entries[2]["mail"]="bbb@yandex.ru";
$entries[3]["displayname"]="Anna";
$entries[3]["mail"]="123@mail.ru";

// --------------------------------- //

$newArr = [];
for ($i = count($entries); $i > 0; --$i) {
    $user = $entries[$i - 1];
    $name = $user['displayname'];
    $mail = $user['mail'];

    if (isset($newArr[$name])) {
        if (strpos('@mail.ru', $mail) !== false) {
            $newArr[$name]['mail'] = $mail;
        }        
    } else {
        $newArr[$name] = ['mail' => $mail];
    }     

    unset($entries[$i - 1]);       
}

print_r($newArr);
// output:

Array
(
    [Anna] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 123@mail.ru
        )    
    [Bob] => Array
        (
            [mail] => bbb@yandex.ru
        )    
    [Ivan] => Array
        (
            [mail] => 123@mail
        )    
)
```

Однако не учтен факт, что могут быть несколько человек с одним именем и почтой mail.ru (Например обе Anna имеют почты на mail.ru)

Comment: ******работает******

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko я кстати забыл `unset` в конце цикла приписать, чтоб  первый массив удалять постепенно и не держать в памяти

Answer (score 0):

В предыдущем ответе изменяется структура результирующего массива, поэтому оставлю свой вариант:

```
<?php

$entries[0]["displayname"]="Ivan";
$entries[0]["mail"]="123@mail";
$entries[1]["displayname"]="Anna";
$entries[1]["mail"]="aaa@yandex.ru";
$entries[2]["displayname"]="Bob";
$entries[2]["mail"]="bbb@yandex.ru";
$entries[3]["displayname"]="Anna";
$entries[3]["mail"]="123@mail.ru";

$temp = [];

foreach ($entries as $item) {
    $temp[] = $item['displayname'];
}

$val = array_count_values($temp);

for ($i = 0, $j = count($entries, COUNT_RECURSIVE); $i < $j; $i++) {
    $int = isset($entries[$i]) ? $val[$entries[$i]['displayname']] : 0;

    if ($int > 1 && strpos($entries[$i]['mail'], 'mail.ru') === false) {
        unset($entries[$i]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($entries); echo '</pre>';
```

> Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [displayname] => Ivan
            [mail] => 123@mail
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [displayname] => Bob
            [mail] => bbb@yandex.ru
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [displayname] => Anna
            [mail] => 123@mail.ru
        )

)
```

Comment: вам тоже большое спасибо. но вторым ответом не получится.

Comment: @Oleg Zolotarenko это не столь важно :)